# selenium-cucumber, how to call from custom_steps.rb

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I have this code, I put it in the file custom_steps like this :

```
Then(/^can assign multitimes$/) do
 assignee = $driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*
 [@id="left"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[5]/div[2]')
  if assignee.text().include? ','
  puts "Failed (request cannot be assigned to otherusers)"
  else
  puts "Passed (request cannot be assigned to otherusers)"
end
end
```

How can I call the above code in my .feature file ?

Thanks, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange your feature file and step def in following folder structure.

```
/features/YourSpecific.feature
/features/step_definitions/custom_steps.rb
```

Make sure you have installed cucumber gem for Ruby runtime environment. Just navigate to /feautures/ and run.

```
$user>cucumber YourSpecific.feature
```